# Analytically comparing two convex programs

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

Hi I want to find the relationship  between two convex programs

**************************

P1:
\begin{equation}
Z_1 = \min_x f(x)
\end{equation}
S.T.
\begin{equation}
Ax = b\\
\sum_{ij}x_{ij} = 1\\
0 \le x_{i,j} \le 1
\end{equation}

**************************

P2:
\begin{equation}
Z_2 = \min_x f(x)
\end{equation}
S.T.
\begin{equation}
Ax = b\\
\sum_{i}x_{ij} = 1, \forall j\\
0 \le x_{i,j} \le 1
\end{equation}

How do I proceed to find a relationship b below-

$Z_1 \overset{?}{b}  Z_2$

i.e. whether $b$ is $"\le", "\ge"$ or $=$?

In the above program, $f$ is a convex function.

Comment: It seems that the feasible sets of both problems are "unrelated", in a sense that none of them is contained within the other. So without additional assumptions, I believe that no such relationship can be established.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Since the constraint in P1 is a hyperplane and in P2 is the intersection of hyperplanes. I believe we could say that the hyperplane of P1 is always below the intersection of hyperplanes of P2. Any suggestions?